# need to find which shape is large and which shape is small from python opencv code

Tags: python, opencv

i have a opencv code. where i have to merge code for detecting small, medium, and large objects from this image [from this image and have to show which is large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1JhD.jpg). i can show which is large and small in descending order. but cant show which is big and which is small through that picture. any kind of help will be great. if you dont understand the question ask me please. i really need the solve.

Comment: First, you should invert your threshold image so the rectangles are white on black background. Then you should use cv2.EXTERNAL for your contours. Once you have contours, you can find the areas using cv2.contourArea(). Then you can compare contours to find the largest and smallest.

Comment: can you give me a example code. that will be very helpful. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

Convert to grayscale and use Otsu thresholding. Then invert the thresholded image so that the rectangles are white on black background. Then get the external contours. Then get the min and max area rectangles and the bounding boxes and print those statistics.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('2rectangles.jpg')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# invert so rectangles are white on black background
thresh = 255 - thresh

# get contours
result = img.copy()
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]

# get largest and smallest contour by area
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
little_contour = min(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# get location and area
area1 = cv2.contourArea(big_contour)
x1,y1,w1,h1 = cv2.boundingRect(big_contour)
cv2.rectangle(result, (x1, y1), (x1+w1, y1+h1), (0, 0, 255), 2)
print("red - largest rectangle x,y,w,h,area:",x1,y1,w1,h1,area1)

area2 = cv2.contourArea(little_contour)
x2,y2,w2,h2 = cv2.boundingRect(little_contour)
cv2.rectangle(result, (x2, y2), (x2+w2, y2+h2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
print("green - smallest rectangle x,y,w,h,area:",x2,y2,w2,h2,area2)

# save resulting image
cv2.imwrite('2rectangles_result.jpg',result)

# show thresh and result    
cv2.imshow("bounding_boxes", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Resulting Bounding Boxes - largest in red and smallest in green:

[image]

Comment: can you please help me in one more thing? how can i merge this two codes? i need to show wether its a round or rectangle shape and get the small big one too.

Comment: You can use my code up to and including the contour detection using external contours. Then sort the contours by area using cv2.contourArea. Then use your for loop to do the cv2.approxPolyDP to determine how many vertices.